# Let $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ be $n$ independent random variables such that each $Y_i \sim POI(\beta x_i) $

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ be $n$ independent random variables such that each $Y_i \sim POI(\beta x_i) $, where $\beta$ is an unknown parameter. If $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$ is a dataset where $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ are the observed values based on $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$, then find the least squares estimator of $\beta$.

The thing is I know how to find the MLE of $\beta$. But how to find the LSE, especially what is the model specified here??
Can anyone help?

Comment: I agree it is an odd question. If you assume $\beta$ is random and uniform over some interval you will get one answer, if you assume it has an exponential distribution with some parameter you will get a different answer.

Comment: On the other hand, you can certainly compute an unbiased estimator and, assuming the data is independent, you can compute the mean square error. You could in fact optimize over a class of linear processing on the data.

Comment: Can you say: If the sum of squares of the errors is $S = \sum (\hat \beta x_i - y_i)^2$,

then $\frac{dS}{d\hat\beta} = \sum 2 \hat \beta(\hat \beta x_i - y_i) = 2 \hat \beta\left(\hat\beta \sum x_i - \sum y_i\right)$,

so the sum of squares is minimised when $\hat\beta = \frac{\sum y_i}{\sum x_i}$